# Problems with header sub total in active reports?

Tags: c#, activereports

How can you create a group-header subtotal in ActiveReports without having to precalculate the total?

Currently my first group total is showing up as 0 and my subtotals are ending up on the next groups header total.

I have a text box with DataField = TotalCost where TotalCost is a Field being used to sum my Detail section. The textBox Summary properties are:

- SummaryFunc: Sum
- SumamryGroup: GroupHeader
- SummaryRunning: Group
- SummaryType: SubTotal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple but active reports documentation isn't the greatest. Setting "SummaryRunning" = None should do it. "Group" only works for the footer section.

- DataField: TotalCost
- SummaryGroup: GroupHeader
- SummaryRunning: None
- SummaryType: SubTotal